How to center the caption of an image without overriding the caption style of aa.cls?
MWE:
\documentclass{aa}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{1.png}
\caption{Algorithm flow}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}



Depends on the unknown aa class. If it loads package caption, you can locally switch on singlelinecheck.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz IMHO it is a bad question style, to not link classes, that are not available from CTAN. Questioners should learn, how to ask good questions. BTW: It seems to be a non-free publisher class. So the publisher should do the support. Sorry. Moreover, if the publisher configures captions to be left aligned, authors should not change this.

For the image you posted, it looks better to leave it as is, and if I was the publisher I would get very upset if you did. As others said we need more info on the class, but you can leave an empty line or type \par after the figure and hope it works.

Thank you all for your effective responses

You could temporarily modify the caption font to include \centering (don't use this if you plan to submit the paper):
\documentclass{aa}  

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!ht]
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\aa@captionfont}{\centering}{}{}
\makeatother
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Algorithm flow}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}



You missed an opportunity to use LaTeX hooks!

@yannisl Not a missed opportunity, but a chance for more users to post answers :)
